# C++, left/right rotation of std::list

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, vector, rotation

Is there any way how to use `std::rotate` for the list

```
std::list<int> v = { 0,7, 1,2 };
```

since these left/right rotations

```
std::rotate(v.begin(), v.begin() + 1, v.end());
std::rotate(v.rbegin(), v.rbegin() + 1, v.rend());
```

work for the vector?

```
std::vector<int> v = { 0, 7, 1, 2 };
```

One possible way is to copy the list to the vector

```
std::vector<int> u{ std::begin(v), std::end(v) };
```

and vice versa but I found it too "lengthy"... A direct rotation of the list leads to the following errors:

```
Error   C2672   'std::rotate': no matching overloaded function found    
Error   C2676   binary '+':  std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your issue is not rotate, but the iterator type; `std::list` has [BidirectionalIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator). They don't implement `operator+`. You have to iterate to the point you want to have as new first... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/633363afbc94a64a

Comment: BTW: You could simply implement an `operator+` overload for your needs; [quick and dirty](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1646818e9382e92).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only syntactical issue with the invocation

```
 std::rotate(v.begin(), v.begin() + 1, v.end());
```

is that `std::list` iterators don't model [random access iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) but [bidirectional iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator). Therefore, you can't add or subtract integral values to/from them. Instead, call `std::rotate` like this

```
std::rotate(v.begin(), std::next(v.begin()), v.end());
std::rotate(v.rbegin(), std::next(v.rbegin()), v.rend());
```

Here, `std::next` increments your iterator, no matter what concept it satifies. That's why it's sometimes better to use it in the first place (in your case, when using a `std::vector`), as it adds one level of indirection as opposed to `someIterator + 1`, where you hard-wire the random access requirement.

Comment: I wouldn't call that “the only issue”. By far.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I see your point. "Only" was meant to address the syntactical part of the code. I'll clarify it.

Answer (score 10):

You can't add to `std::list` iterator since it's not random access. But you can increment it. And that's what `std::next` does for  you:

```
template< class Item >
void rot_slow( std::list<Item>& seq )
{
    std::rotate( seq.begin(), next( seq.begin() ), seq.end() );
}
```

However, this logic, using `std::rotate`, uses O(n) swap operations.

That's needlessly inefficient. If you want to rotate through all items in the list that's O(n²) complexity. It quickly gets very slow.

Instead just splice the first item in at the end of the list:

```
template< class Item >
void rot_fast( std::list<Item>& seq )
{
    seq.splice( seq.end(), seq, seq.begin() );
}
```

This uses 0 item swaps, O(1) complexity.

Comment: Somehow I was expecting/hoping that rotate has an overload for list iterators ...

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. See the standard. **The behavior is undefined if other refers to the same object as *this.**  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: Thanks, but the UB for splicing from self only applies to the overloads with 2 arguments, i.e. attempting to move all of the list into a position in the list (which is generally impossible).

It's easy to misunderstand. In fact, at first I corrected the code and wrote: ❝Thanks, you're right, splicing from itself is UB. That was surprising restriction. I've corrected the code to just use a temporary list.❞